# Sorting an array in a foreach loop in php

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I am looking at how to sort an array within a `foreach` loop to place my featured jobs to the top of the list.

The key and values are `'Featured Job' => 'Yes'` or `'Featured Job' => 'No'`

I am just checking to see if the key `isset` and then outputting a string saying 'Featured Job' - that part was easy. I am just unable to sort them to place the featured jobs at the top.

Here is my code, any hints or help would be appreciated:

```
    if( isset($v->customLovs) && !empty($v->customLovs->customLov) ) {
        $lovs = $v->customLovs->customLov;

      if( isset($lovs->label) )
        $lovs = array( $lovs );

      foreach( $lovs as $lov ) {
        switch( $lov->label ) {
          case "Position":
            $position = $lov->criteria->criterion->label;
            break;
          case "Town or City":
            $townOrCity = $lov->criteria->criterion->label;
            break;
          case "Featured Job":
            $fjob = $lov->criteria->criterion->label;
            break;                
        }
      }
    }
```

And here is the output:

```
<h2><?php echo $position;?></h2>
<?php if ( isset($fjob) ) : ?>Featured Job<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $townOrCity;?>
```

My feeble attempt to cure this was like so:

`$lovs = usort($lovs);`

I can only assume that I need to target the `$fjob` somehow?

Comment: Do a `usort` before looping?

Comment: @JonStirling - this is something I tried on ```$lovs``` but it seemingly had zero effect. Unless I was putting it in the wrong place?

Comment: Maybe? I don't know, I wasn't there ;)

Comment: @JonStirling - haha I cannot argue with that! could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://php.net/usort or put your sorting attempt in your question so we can have a look.

Comment: @JonStirling - see my updated answer - I am just looking at the link provided

Comment: Yep,your attempt is incomplete, the link might need a couple of takes, but everything you need is in there.

Comment: @JonStirling - the issue I am encountering is that before the loop the variable doesn't exist yet so I'm not able to target it...Unless I am missing the point?

Answer (score 0):

You can look up php documentation on sorting arrays. you can create a date key and sort by the date.
 http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: you can create a variable that holds your featured jobs, then write an if statement asking- if the featured job is in the array... sort by the featured job

Comment: Would it be possible to perhaps show me an example because that is exactly where I am struggling because the variable is yet to exist - is it possible in the last case?